# How to print data from taken from csv in Jmeter console

Tags: jmeter

How to print data, reading from csv in Jmeter console ?I want to just cross verify the data that jmeter is gettingfrom csv?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to "print" the variables values anywhere, you can observe them at any time using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

However if printing the variable value to [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) is an absolute must you can do it using any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following simple line of Groovy code:

```
println(vars.get('your_variable_name_here'))
```

Demo:

[image]